# How do I uninstall this Adobe program?

Tags: uninstall, adobe

I recently installed this version of Adobe Acrobat Reader DC using the instructions at this page:
https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-adobe-acrobat-reader-dc-wine-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux

It's practically useless to me because some basic features cause the thing to crash. How do I UNINSTALL it correctly?

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open a terminal and enter the command:

```
sudo snap remove --purge acrordrdc
```

This will remove the app and its configuration files.

Hop this helps